# getUser() Method on ApiAssistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to get the `User_id` from a request. Currently I am just using `API.AI` to build the skill before wiring in the actual `Google Home API`. When I use the following snippet, I get

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
>       at Assistant.ApiAiAssistant.getUser"

```
const assistant = new ApiAiAssistant({request: request, response: response});
let userId = assistant.getUser().user_id;
```

Am I just unable to use the `getUser()` method when testing directly with `API.AI`? Do I need to fully deploy and test with the `Home Simulator` in order to make a call to `getUser()` without causing an error?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug in the client library for this method for certain cases. Will be fixed in next client library update.

Comment: Fixed in version 1.0.5